# Use of unresolved identifier 'Snapshot' in Swift5 when I'm trying to use firebase

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

I have imported the following:

`import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseDatabase`

I am trying use this line of code 

`let currentUserDoc = snapshot?.documents.first(where: { ($0["uid"] as? String) == UserId })`
but xcode says "Use of unresolved identifier 'snapshot'. What does that mean and how do I fix it so it disappears.

Comment: What is snapshot equal to?

Comment: What is snapshot usually equal to? I always find it in the StackOverflow answers, but I do not know what it's referring to. For example, the answer in this link uses it too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58470066/grab-the-current-users-first-name-cloud-firebase-swift

Comment: did you try the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getDocuments()`:

```
var userName = db.collection("users").getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
    } else {
        //do something
            let currentUserDoc = snapshot?.documents.first(where: { ($0["uid"] as? String) == UserId })

            }
```